# How to replace mysql table with updated one without dropping table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using mysql table on my website where I update table frequently.  Instead of altering table on remote server I do it on localhost and then upload it. While uploading I drop table first which causes problem for website user for a moment.

Is there anyway to replace table without dropping.

Comment: You should probably have a way to update the table in place built into your application. Sounds more like a design problem to me.

Comment: Usually when you update table it is mainly column Changes, for any new column I suggest to have some default value set, this way simply running a SQL query against database fix the problem without downtime. when you update table PHPMyadmin shows Alter query, just save them for live update. and run them as it is on live DB usually make your life easier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can upload the table with a temporary name. After the upload completes you can drop the original and rename the temporary.
In this way the downtime would be very limited.